Restrict Content Pro auto renewal and subscriptions issue
Restrict Content Pro: our all memberships are showing blank Gateway Customer ID and Gateway Subscription ID.
I have copied these details from Stripe and pasted in RCP memberships but I have 2 issues: 1. some memberships auto renewed and some marked expired again. 2. when I manually assigned a membership and attached customer ID and subscription id, it created another subscription in Stripe and older subscription is also actve in Stripe.

So I am concerned if they will only be charged new subscription or both & and how can I connect only old subscriptions with users in RCP?
